# Select an element inside an HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, find, placeholder

I have a template as below:

```
<script type="text/template" id="editorItemPlacholder">
    <div>
    ...
    </div>
</script>
```

And create an instance of the template like this:

```
var editorItemTemplate = $("#editorItemPlacholder").html();
```

Then I want to change the id of an element inside the template, each time I make an instance of it. So I think I must use this:

```
editorItemTemplate.find("div").prop("id",item);
```

but this doesn't work. And the sign is that the code doesn't go after this line. What is wrong with this type of selection? How can I make change in that template.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a jQuery function in a html element. You can not use `find` into `$editorItemTemplate`, which contains the html of the template.

You have to find the element using this way:

```
$('div', $editorItemTemplate).prop('id', item);
```

Regards.